# How to make sure the user enter an image (FORM ANGULAR)

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am making a form, this form contains text (name, age…) and one image.
Right now I can make sure the text are necessary by using a FormGroup but I would like to make sure that the form is valid ONLY IF the image is entered.

So I tried this way: (HTML file)

```
<input   formControlName="photo" type="file" (click)="selectImage()">
```

and the TS file:

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.sellingSneakForm = new FormGroup({
  photo: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
});}
```

with the functions:

```
selectImage() {

let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
  title: 'Add an image',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Take a picture from camera',
      role: 'CAMERA',

      handler: () => {
        this.takePicture();
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Choose from your gallery',
      role: 'GALLERY',

      handler: () => {
        this.selectPicture();
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel',
      handler: () => {

      }
    }
  ]
});
actionSheet.present();}

takePicture() {
this.camera.getPicture({
  quality : 95,
  destinationType : this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  sourceType : this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  targetWidth: 500,
  targetHeight: 500,
}).then(imageData => {
  this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;      // imageData is a base64 encoded string
  this.Picture = imageData;       //this.Picture is passing the string to our DB
}, error => {
  console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
});}
```

It is working 100% when I upload the image but my app does not need the image to push the item to the database… It is what I would like with this FormGroup and FormControl ==> make sure the user has entered an image..

Is it possible this way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am trying an other way at the same time like:
uploading the image only if the field item.picture is not empty but it does not work as I need the key of the item when uploading (and I don't want to upload it before it has entered an image..)

So a kind of form control would be appreciated if someone knows it's existence